Access HTTP Trailer in Quarkus
I'm implementing a REST-API in Quarkus and want to stream the content.
I want the know when the tranpsort of the stream is finished. As the http-standard describes, http-trailer fields will be sent, when the transport of the message-body is finished. Therefore I want to access the http-trailer in quarkus (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Trailer).
How do I access the http trailer information in quarkus?
Thanks for your support.
I've read the documentation - there is only some documentation about grpc, where you can use the http-trailers:
https://quarkus.io/guides/grpc-service-consumption
But I need the information in Quarkus REST.

The Vert.x HTTP Client gives you access to HTTP trailers via io.vertx.core.http.HttpClientResponse#trailers.
You can manually create a Vert.x HTTP client in Quarkus doing something like:
@Singleton
public MyClass {

    private final Vertx vertx;
    private final WebClient client;            
    
    public MyClass(Vertx vertx) {
        this.vertx = vertx;
        this.client = WebClient.create(vertx); 
    }

}

See this for more information.
